# How to solve this question?

Tags: general-topology

Show   that  if  $B$  is  a  basis for  a  topology  on  $X$ , then  the  topology  generated  by  $B$ is equal to the  intersection  of  all   topologies  on  $X$   that  contain   $B$.

Comment: I'm a little confused: for any family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of a set $X$, the topology generated by $\mathcal{F}$ is **by definition** the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that contain $\mathcal{F}$.  So what is there to show?

Comment: @Pete: Isn't there also another definition of the topology generated by $B$ as the set of arbitrary unions of elements of $B$? If that is so, the question would amount to showing the equivalence of these two definitions.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks for you comment: it is indeed a plausible interpretation of the question.  (I actually had a similar thought after I made my comment, but rather than address it I chose to go to sleep...)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, as joriki suggests, the question is to show that for a base $\mathcal{B}$ for a topology on $X$, the family $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}$ of arbitrary unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ -- including, I suppose, the empty union, which gives the empty set -- is the smallest topology containing $\mathcal{B}$.

If so, this is certainly true and can be shown as follows:

Step 1: Since any topology is closed under arbitrary unions, any topology $\tau$ containing $\mathcal{B}$ must contain $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}$, so it is enough to show that $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}$ is a topology.

Recall that what we are assuming about $\mathcal{B}$ is that

(B1) $\bigcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B = X$ and
(B2) For all $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, if $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then there exists 
$B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

Step 2: Thus $\emptyset, X$ are unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$: the former by taking the empty union, the latter by (B1).

Step 3: Being the set of all unions of a certain family of sets, $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}$ is certainly closed under arbitrary unions.

Step 4: So the matter of it is to show that $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}$ is closed under finite intersections.  For this, it is enough to show that if $U_1,U_2 \in \tau_{\mathcal{B}}$, then so is $U_1 \cap U_2$.  To show this we need to use condition (B2), which notice has not yet been used.  This verification takes two or three lines.  I urge the OP to try it herself and tell us whether she succeeded and if not what she tried.